# Django: Detect client browser support of HTML5

Tags: python, django, html

Is there any module out there that could be used by my Django site to tell whether the client browser supports HTML5 and what features are supported?

Comment: why not use ajax and modernizer to report back once the page has loaded?

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony - I am, indeed, using modernizr. But what I need here is a way to detect HTML5 support prior to the generation of HTML response

Comment: Does it have to be the first response? You could keep track of their moderinzer settings in the session once they've loaded a page. Otherwise it's going to guess work: you'll have to use User Agent's etc. which isn't reliable at all (it's similar to the problem of trying to guess what resolution the user has for serving up mobile/tablet pages)

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony - I guess that's the best I can do for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly no. This is something that you'll need JavaScript client to do. Especially something like http://modernizr.com/

One way to do it would be to run modernizr and send results to back end.

If you would be really optimistic, you could build a list of User-Agents and decide upon that. But good luck with keeping which things works in which version of Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: if 'ie' in user_agent.lower(): return false;